# Change getSupportActionBar().setTitle value from another class

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a class that gets actionbarsherlock oncreate and sets default values. How can I change this values from another class ?

sample codes that doesnt work :

```
public class MyActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
 public static String abs;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       abs = "text";
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle(abs);
}
}
```

External class:

```
MyActivity.abs = "new value";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely not the recommended way to set the title, however, it should work if you remove the assignment `abs = "text";` ...

```
public class MyActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
    public static String abs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       getSupportActionBar().setTitle(abs);
    }
}
```

... and call `MyActivity.abs = "new value";`some where *before* the activity is created the first time.

Anyhow I'd propose to pass the title as an extra into the activity ...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("title", "Another Headline");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

... and evaluate that one from the intent:

```
public class MyActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String title = "Default Headline";
        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("title")) {    
            title = intent.getStringExtra("title");   
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

**p.s.** setting title after creation:

If you can reference the activity directly, for instance because you are in a fragment, you might add a method like ...

```
public class MyActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    ....
}
```

... and call it accordingly:

```
getActivity().setTitle("Another Headline");
```

The most sophisticated way to pass any kind of arguments to existing activities allowing them to process them in any way would be using a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    public static final String SET_TITLE_ACTION = "com.myapp.SET_TITLE_ACTION";
    public static final IntentFilter INTENT_FILTER = createIntentFilter();

    private SetTitleReceiver setTitleReceiver = new SetTitleReceiver();

    private static IntentFilter createIntentFilter() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(SET_TITLE_ACTION);
        return filter;
    }

    protected void registerSetTitleReceiver() {
        registerReceiver(setTitleReceiver, INTENT_FILTER);
    }

    protected void unRegisterSetTitleReceiver() {
        unregisterReceiver(setTitleReceiver);
    }

    public class SetTitleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(SET_TITLE_ACTION)) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("title")) {    
                    title = intent.getStringExtra("title");   
                    this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any `Activity` class that should be able to receive a title change has to register the `BroadcasdtReceiver` in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`. This way you can set the title of these activity instance by sending a broadcast event from anywhere:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.SET_TITLE_ACTION);
intent.putExtra("title", "Another Headline");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for help. I must set title after the activity is created the first time. And I need to use settext dynamicly : I mean just settext value must change, page wont be change/refresh. When I use intent, main page will be change/refresh I think, isnt it ?

Comment: See above: the easiest solution would be applicable if you can get a reference on the created activity. You could assign such a reference in the `onCreate()` of the activity (may be supply it to appropriate observers, or simply using a static list). Using a `BroadcastReceiver` is the most flexible way, at least from a certain perspectice

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because your just changing the reference `abs` is pointing to.
If you want to change the title pass the SherlockActivity as a parameter to your method.

Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new ChangeTitle(this).setTitle("test title");
    }
}

class ChangeTitle {
    String title;
    SherlockActivity activity;

    public ChangeTitle(SherlockActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(this.title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is class ChangeTitle inner class of MyActivity ? I need to use MyActivity as main activity and set default value to it. Then class External (in another java file ) will change its value dynamicly. I'm a bit confused with codes about how to use them.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an inner class to MyActivity. It just needs a reference to the SherlockActivity.